# Why is my App Store saying it needs my to give it my credit card?

Tags: iphone, itunes-store

So, I'm trying to get a make up cam for danTDM photos (lol) so I'm trying to get it and it's free and I haven't gotten a app in a long time and then it came up! GIVE US CREDIT CARD. And so I tryed it again and BOOM it asks again! So now I look at all these things saying what to do and yet again, I can't do it... It says press the "none" credit card... WITCH I DONT HAVE! WHAT DO I DO HELP!